# Taking image from camera in Background Service

Tags: service, background, camera

I'm creating app which will work as background service and will take image from front camera periodically without preview and app must be stay background. I found source in one forum. People says that code is work but for me this code not work. I cannot take picture.

Help me to fix this code please. Sorry for my english =)

```
public class CamService extends Service {



        private static final String TAG = "CameraDemo";



        private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =

               Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);



        Camera camera;

        ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle;





        /* Service Life cycle Overrides */

        @Override

        public void onCreate() {

                super.onCreate();

                camera = Camera.open();

                try {

                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);

                } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                }

                takePicsPeriodically(5);

        }



        @Override

        public void onDestroy() {

                stopPics();

                super.onDestroy();

        }



        @Override

        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

                return null;

        }

        /* ----------------------------------- */



       private IMyRemoteService.Stub myRemoteServiceStub = new IMyRemoteService.Stub() {



                /* Basic Service Methods */

                public boolean isCollecting() {

                        return (beeperHandle != null);

                }

                /* ------------------------- */

        };



        public void takePicsPeriodically(long period) {

        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {

                public void run() 
                { 
                    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback,rawCallback,jpegCallback); 

                }

            };

        camera.startPreview();

        beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, period, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }



        public void stopPics() {

                beeperHandle.cancel(true);

                beeperHandle = null;

                camera.stopPreview();

        camera.release();

        camera = null;

        }



        /* Camera Call backs */

        ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

                public void onShutter() {

                        Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");

                }

        };



        /** Handles data for raw picture */

        PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {

                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");

                }

        };



        /** Handles data for j peg picture */

        PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

                        try {

                                // write to local sand box file system

                                //outStream = CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);   

                                // Or write to s d card

                                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));

                                outStream.write(data);

                                outStream.close();

                                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {

                        }

                        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");

                }

        };





    }
```

Comment: Did you define your Service in Manifest file? The above code is working fine in my device Android 2.3.6/Samsung S5360 but when I run it in Samsung S7562 it doesn't work out.

Comment: I am already leave this project, but if my mind not lie me, I defined it in my manifest